# NoConverterFound error in SQLAdmin while working with PostgreSQL ARRAY type

Tags: python, api, sqlalchemy

I am using the SQLAdmin python package with SQLModel library in the FastAPI app to create an admin dashboard for a model that has an array field and experience the following error:

```
 ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662449+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662449+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 372, in run_asgi
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662450+00:00 app[web.1]: result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662451+00:00 app[web.1]: return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662457+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 261, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662457+00:00 app[web.1]: await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662458+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662459+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exc
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662459+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662460+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662460+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 84, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662461+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662461+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662462+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exc
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662462+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662462+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662463+00:00 app[web.1]: raise e
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662463+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662464+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662464+00:00 app[web.1]: await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662464+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 408, in handle
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662465+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662465+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662465+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662465+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662466+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exc
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662466+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662466+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662466+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662466+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exc
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662467+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662467+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662467+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662467+00:00 app[web.1]: await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662468+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662468+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.app(scope, receive, send)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662468+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662469+00:00 app[web.1]: response = await func(request)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqladmin/application.py", line 351, in edit
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662471+00:00 app[web.1]: Form = await model_admin.scaffold_form()
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662471+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqladmin/models.py", line 834, in scaffold_form
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662471+00:00 app[web.1]: return await get_model_form(
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqladmin/forms.py", line 415, in get_model_form
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662472+00:00 app[web.1]: field = await converter.convert(
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqladmin/forms.py", line 232, in convert
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662472+00:00 app[web.1]: converter = self.get_converter(model=model, prop=prop)
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqladmin/forms.py", line 116, in get_converter
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662473+00:00 app[web.1]: raise NoConverterFound(  # pragma: nocover
2022-06-03T19:03:11.662474+00:00 app[web.1]: sqladmin.exceptions.NoConverterFound: Could not find field converter for column series (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.ARRAY'>).
```

This error is thrown when I am trying to edit the following entity:

```py
class ShowCreate(SQLModel):
    title: str
    description: str
    language: Language = Field(sa_column=Column(Enum(Language)))
    show_copyright: str
    category: Category = Field(sa_column=Column(Enum(Category)))
    series: Set[str] = Field(default=None, sa_column=Column(ARRAY(String())))
```

I understand that the problem is caused by the series field, but I really need to store a list of strings in PostgreSQL and have the ability to modify the Show entity from the SQLAdmin dashboard.
Is there any way to explain SQLAdmin how to handle array type?

Comment: Please add the code that raises this exception and the full traceback.

Comment: @ljmc, extended description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I did additonal investigation and found out that sqladmin supports following convertors:

```
{
    'dialects.mssql.base.BIT': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_Boolean of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'Boolean': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_Boolean of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'Date': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_Date of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'DateTime': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_DateTime of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'Enum': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_Enum of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'MANYTOMANY': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_ManyToMany of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'ONETOMANY': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_ManyToMany of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'MANYTOONE': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_ManyToOne of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.INET': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_PGInet of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.MACADDR': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_PGMacaddr of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.UUID': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_PgUuid of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'CHAR': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_String of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'String': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_String of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'LargeBinary': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_Text of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'Text': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_Text of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'Binary': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_Text of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'sqlalchemy_utils.types.email.EmailType': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_UtilsEmail of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'sqlalchemy_utils.types.ip_address.IPAddressType': "<bound method ModelConverter.conv_UtilsIP of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'JSON': "<bound method ModelConverter.convert_JSON of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'Numeric': "<bound method ModelConverter.handle_decimal_types of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>",
    'Integer': "<bound method ModelConverter.handle_integer_types of <sqladmin.forms.ModelConverter object at 0x10637fb80>>"
}
```

So, there is OneToMany support available, but no ARRAY.

The solution I took for my system is to create a new Table and use OneToMany.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your issue in SQLAlchemy only, which I expected since the traceback seems to be an issue with getting the converter for `<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.ARRAY'>` within SQLAdmin.

This is the generic `ARRAY` type, you could try to use the [`postgresql.ARRAY`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) type directly.

If that still does not work, you should file an issue with SQLAdmin, the authors might be able to help you better.

PS: storing an array in a row violates the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), you might want to think about that.